# How do I install both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of a COM DLL and "auto-select"?

Tags: com, 32bit-64bit

We've got a DLL (a COM server) that will compile fine in 32-bit and 64-bit, but the DLL uses the same CLSID and AppID for the 32-bit version and the 64-bit version. Is this OK or does this have to change?

I'm asking this because apparently on a 64-bit machine, we can't register the 32-bit version and the 64-bit version together.  It would be nice if 32-bit client applications could automatically use the 32-bit DLL, and 64-bit client applications could automatically use the 64-bit DLL.

On a related note, we have the source code and Visual Studio 2005 project file for a client application ... how do we compile a 32-bit and 64-bit version of the same application? It's a C# application, and it includes a reference to our COM server DLL like this:

> `<ItemGroup> <COMReference Include="ComServer">`
>
> `<Guid>{C1FADEA6-68FD-4F43-9FC2-0BC451FA5D53}</Guid>`
>
> `<VersionMajor>830</VersionMajor> <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>`
>
> `<Lcid>0</Lcid> <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool> <Isolated>False</Isolated>`
>
> `</COMReference> </ItemGroup>`

If it turns out that we need a separate CLSID for 64-bit, how do we make this reference "only for the 32-bit configuration" in Visual Studio? Or do we have to have separate projects with the same source code: one that refers to 32-bit DLL, and the other that refers to 64-bit DLL?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both versions can (and indeed should) use the same GUIDs for everything.

On a 32-bit machine you can't register or use the 64-bit DLL, so there's no problem there. The 64-bit DLL simply doesn't enter the picture.

On a 64-bit machine the 64-bit DLL gets registered in HKLM/Software/Classes/CLSID (etc.) and the 32-bit DLL gets registered in HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/Classes/CLSID. (I wonder where you got the advice that you can't register the 32-bit DLL on a 64-bit machine...) A 32-bit client running on the 64-bit machine will look in the normal place in the registry, but the OS will silently redirect it to the Wow6432Node key instead.

Comment: Forgot to say... on the 64-bit machine there's a 32-bit version of regsvr32.dll in \Windows\SysWow64\ for registering 32-bit DLLs in the Wow6432Node area. (You'll just have to get used to the thoroughly counter-intuitive naming pattern.) We had a problem with our installer - on a 64-bit machine it wouldn't use the 32-bit regsvr32.dll, but we needed to install a 32-bit DLL. So we ended up writing our own version and running it explicitly.

Comment: At least on Win7, regsvr32.exe is clever enough to call the other version of itself automatically if you run it against the opposite type of DLL. (That goes for both 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs and versions of regsvr32.exe.)

Comment: @Leo: Thanks for the tip. I'd read about that but found that it didn't work for me on Vista, so I figured it was just something that had fallen between the cracks. I only started testing on Win7 after I'd finished the installer.

Comment: We knew that 32-bit DLLs can be registered with C:\Windows\SysWOW64. But we're trying to compile as both 32-bit-native and 64-bit-native, and it would be nice if existing 32-bit and new 64-bit apps could work on the same machine. (The DLL is an Automation programming library for our flagship database product, and the client application would use the programming lib to work with the product.)

Comment: That should work fine. Your 32-bit client will load the 32-bit server, and the 64-bit client will load the 64-bit server. No need for you to change anything. Compile both versions from the same source code and carry on as usual. Just be sure your registration does the right thing, as mentioned in the comments here.

Answer (score 8):

This is dealt with inside Windows with a feature called '[Registry redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'  On the 64-bit version of Windows, a 32-bit program gets a different view of the registry. Any access to the HKCR alias or the HKLM\Software root is redirected for the kind of keys that a COM server uses.  A 32-bit program actually sees the key values stored in HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node.  You can see it with Regedit.exe

This is normally taken care of by an installer, a VS Setup project has the TargetPlatform property for example.  If you want to make the COM server available in both 32-bit and 64-bit mode then you should use two installers.  Or a 64-bit installer that writes both sets of keys.  Having a COM server that can handle both is *very* unusual in the olden days.  But not unheard of when you implemented in .NET for example.