# VBA trouble with active-x reference

Tags: excel, vba, printing, reference, controls

I want to program a control for a printer. The interface for the printer is the "Legitronic" software from "Weber Packaging Solutions". In the vba-activex manual it is written that a instance get build as followed:

for late binding:

```
Dim MyLabel as Object
Set MyLabel = CreateObject("Legi32.label")
```

for early binding:

```
Dim MyLabel as Legi32.label
Set MyLabel = CreateObject("Legi32.label")
```

I referred to the Type Library of the Interface (my workmate told me it is the right reference, because he done a program in the past too and it worked for him)

But everytime I execute the program i get the run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object.

I use the IDE of a Microsoft Excel-Worksheet with Macros (.xlsm)

Do you know this problem or know, how it could be solved?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: You don't need to use `CreateObject()` with early binding, just use the `New` keyword. It looks like `.label` is a child object or property of the `Legi32` object - in which case for late binding you would create that object _first_ and then try to access it's properties/methods afterwards

Comment: I tried it with `New` too, but the error code is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with flohdieter for the early binding.

**Early Binding.**
Try setting a reference to the component you are trying to use (Legi32).
If you can't assign a reference to the object, you may have to use RegSvr32 ./somefile to register it on your system. Your workmate may have this registered on his p.c. but you haven't.
Once you can set a reference you should be able to compile your code and use New successfully - unless there's some other issue with the component.

**Late Binding.**
This is where you use the CreateObject("SomeName").
When you create a component, you assign it an Id which gets stored in the Registry. This Id can change due to different versions. Its possible you have a different version installed and are looking for the wrong name.
What I suggest you do, is to open the registry and search for 'Legi32' and see if the Id has a 1 or whatever at the end of the name.

Comment: I've made the registration with RegSvr32 (i tried to register Legi32.tlb) but i got the error message :

`The module "C:\Program Files(x86)\Weber Marking Systems\Legitronic\Bin\Legi32.tlb" may not compatible with the version of Windows that you're running. Check if the module is compatible with an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of regsvr32.exe.`

Comment: Ah. Maybe this similar link may help you with that.... I think you probably need to be explicit on which RegSvr32 exe to use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879418/32-bit-dll-may-not-compatible-on-server-2008-but-works-on-server-2003