# Registering both 32bit and 64bit DLLs

Tags: dll, com, 64-bit, 32-bit, regsvr32

I'm refering to this thread

[How do I install both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of a COM DLL and "auto-select"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403501/how-do-i-install-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-a-com-dll-and-auto-select)

we have exactly the same situation. A namespace extension Dll 32bit and 64bit with same CLSID App ID out of the same project. Now registering those two Dlls works flawlessly. Unregistering brings up some errors. The first unregister works but the second fails. Because I think windows (?) thinks the Dll has already been deregistered...

Do the two Dlls need different CLSIDs and/or App IDs???

Kind regards,
Michael

EDIT:
here's what the DllUnregisterServer does:

```
STDAPI DllUnregisterServer(void){

    _AtlModule.UpdateRegistryAppId(FALSE);
    HRESULT hRes2 = _AtlModule.UnregisterServer(TRUE);
    if (hRes2 != S_OK)
        return hRes2;
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(_afxModuleAddrThis);

    if (!COleObjectFactoryEx::UpdateRegistryAll(FALSE))
        return ResultFromScode(SELFREG_E_CLASS);

     return NOERROR;
}
```

Comment: I guess "some errors" should give you the idea of what goes wrong.

Comment: ok in detail it gives me error code 0x8002801c

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't care - it's `regsvr32` that performs the registration. You use the 32-bit version of `regsvr32` for 32-bit DLLs and the 64-bit version for 64-bit DLLs.

Both version just load the DLL, find `DllRegisterServer()`/`DllUnregisterServer()` entry point, invoke it and observe the returned value. Whatever goes inside is not `regsvr32` business.

Your problem is one of those functions works wrong. You have to debug this. A good start is to use Process Monitor utility to observe what registry accesses are performed and whether they are what you expect.

Comment: hmm, the main frame of the app was not coded by myself, maybe you can see something in the code above...

Comment: @Jesse James: It's impossible to guess. A good start is to use Process Monitor to at least validate the accesses.

Comment: ok, I gave it a try but regsvr32 creats about 100.000 entries, I have no clue for what I should look to solve this...

Comment: @Jesse James: First of all, filter the registry accesses so that only `regsvr32` is reported. Then look for the accesses that yield errors.

Comment: those 100.000 are from regsvr32 ^^ I already filtered that one

Answer (score 0):

Adding more info to the [answer from sharptooth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10416117/501196), if you are unregistering your dll programmatically by excecuting regsvr32, then you might be calling the wrong regsvr32 file. You need to make sure you call regsvr32 from `System32` for unregistering your 64 bit dll and regsvr32 from `SysWow64` for unregistering the 32 bits version. You can p/Invoke the funcion [GetSystemWow64Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for retrieving the SysWow64 folder location.

Comment: I'm trying this under Windows 7 and it can handle both 32 bit and 64 bit, but I also tried calling SysWow64 regsvr32.exe and it doesn't work neither.

Comment: In that case there should be something wrong on your DllUnregisterServer function as sharptooth suggested.

Comment: debugging is hard, I can't see what the content of hRes2 is, it always tells me it can't find that symbol. But it's _AtlModule.UnregisterServer(TRUE); which is not working properly...